# Smallest value of $x^2+5y^2+8z^2$ given $xy+yz+xz=-1$.

Tags: inequality, optimization, contest-math, maxima-minima, qcqp

The question is:

> Find the smallest value of $x^2+5y^2+8z^2$ given $xy+yz+xz=-1$.

Here's what I've tried so far. Dividing by $xyz$, I get $\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}=\frac{1}{-xyz}$. Squaring both sizes:

$$\left( \frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z} \right)^2 = \frac{1}{(xyz)^2}$$

I tried applying Cauchy Schwartz on this:

$$\left( \frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z} \right)^2 \leq 3 \left(\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{y^2}+\frac{1}{z^2}\right)$$

but after this I'm stuck. Can someone help me out here?

I have also tried AM-GM on $x^2+5y^2+8z^2$ but that doesn't seem to lead anywhere.

Wolfram alpha says the answer is $4$.

Comment: Can't you just use Lagrange multipliers?

Comment: Yes, but this question was about inequalities and so I didn't want to take the calc way of doing it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let $k$ be a minimal value.

Thus, $k>0$ and $$x^2+5y^2+8z^2\geq k$$ or
$$x^2+5y^2+8z^2+k(xy+xz+yz)\geq0$$ or
$$x^2+k(y+z)x+5y^2+8z^2+kyz\geq0,$$ for which we need 
$$k^2(y+z)^2-4(5y^2+8z^2+kyz)\leq0$$ or
$$(20-k^2)y^2+(4k-2k^2)yz+(32-k^2)z^2\geq0,$$ for which we need
$$20-k^2>0$$ and $$(2k-k^2)^2-(20-k^2)(32-k^2)=0$$ or
$$k^3-14k^2+160=0$$ or
$$k^3-4k^2-10k^2+40k-40k+160=0$$ or
$$(k-4)(k^2-10k-40)=0,$$ which gives $k=4$.

Easy to see that the equality occurs, which says that we got a minimal value.

Now, we see that
$$x^2+5y^2+8z^2\geq4$$ it's
$$x^2+4(y+z)x+5y^2+8z^2+4yz\geq0$$ or
$$(x+2y+2z)^2+(y-2z)^2\geq0.$$
The equality occurs for $y=2z$, $x=-6z$ and $xy+xz+yz=-1.$

Id est, for example, for  $$(x,y,z)=\left(-\frac{3}{2}, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{4}\right).$$

Comment: Thank you, this is great. I've learnt a new inequality proving trick today

Comment: But actually why must $20-k^2>0$? The equation after that should be enough to conclude $k=4$ right?

Comment: @Yip Jung Hon Since the inequality $(20-k^2)y^2+(4k-2k^2)yz+(32-k^2)z^2\geq0$ is homogeneous, it should be true for any reals $y$ and $z$. For $z=0$ we need $(20-k^2)y^2\geq0$ for any $y$, which gives $20-k^2\geq0$ and easy to see that $20-k^2=0$ is not valid.

Comment: Michael, minor point, not quite "for any reals y and z" right? The inequality only holds when there are values of $xy+yz+zx=-1$, which requires $y +z \neq 0$. Separately, the discriminant condition is $ \geq 0$, and not just $=0$. That yields $k\geq 4$ not just $k=4$.

Comment: @Calvin Li After homogenization $xy+xz+yz$ can be equal to any non-zero real number. By the way, the discriminant should be $\leq0$, but $=0$ it's enough.

Comment: So for example we couldn't have $y  = 0, z = 0$, since that makes $xy+yz+zx=0$.

Comment: @Calvin Li I said non-zero. See please better my previous comment.

Comment: I am agreeing with you, namely that we have $x^2+k(y+z)x+5y^2+8z^2+kyz\geq0,$ when there exists non-zero $xy+yz+zx$. However, I'm pointing out that the condition doesn't apply to "all real $y,z$" because in particular $(0,0)$ doesn't yield a non-zero $xy+yz+zx$. Thankfully, this is the only exception. As I said, it's a minor point.

Comment: To clarify my comment about the discriminant, from $(20-k^2)y^2+(4k-2k^2)yz+(32-k^2)z^2\geq0,$ what we have is that the discriminant $k^3-14k^2+160 \geq 0$ (not $\leq$). It need not only be 0. From there, we can conclude that $k\geq 4$, and then verify that $k=4$ with the equality case. If that's what you mean by "=0 is enough", then I agree with you.

Comment: @Calvin Lin Indeed, $\Delta\leq0$ it's $k^3-14k^2+160\geq0,$ which with $20-k^2>0$ gives $0\leq k\leq4.$